# No entiendo por qué métodos Sort() incide en la dos variables

Tags: javascript

A ver si alguien me puede explicar el motivo por el cual asignando el método sort() a un variable me altera las dos variables que tengo.

```
<script>
let texto="hola"
let arrayTexto=Array.from(texto); 
let textoOrdenado=arrayTexto;
textoOrdenado.sort();
console.log(arrayTexto)
console.log(textoOrdenado)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma diferente de hacerlo, sin usar [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) y utilizando la [sintaxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) de Javascript, sería la siguiente:

```js
let texto = 'hola';

// convierte la cadena en un array usando split
let arrayTexto = texto.split('');
// obtiene una copia del array original usando sintaxis spread y aplica sort sobre dicha copia
let arrayOrdenado = [...arrayTexto].sort();

console.log(arrayTexto);
console.log(arrayOrdenado);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top:0;
}
```

En el código anterior he utilizado el método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) disponible en los objetos de tipo `String`. Éste método devuelve un `Array` separando la cadena según un separador pasado como argumento al método `split()`. Para separar la cadena en sus caracteres que la componen el argumento pasado a `split` es el de carácter vacío: `''`.

Usando el operador spread (`...`), hago una copia del `array` original y lo almaceno en otra variable, además puedo encadenar el método `sort()` directamente, ya que esto: `[ ...Array]` devuelve un `Array`, por lo cual puedo aplicar directamente `sort`.

En tu pregunta tienes esta línea:

```
let textoOrdenado=arrayTexto;
```

En dicha linea estás copiando una dirección de memoria y no un valor. Es un error bastante común que cometemos todos cuando estamos aprendiendo a programar (no sólo en Javascript, sino en casi cualquier otro lenguaje).

El problema en tu código es que es linea no está creando un nuevo objeto a partir de otro, está copiando la dirección de memoria (una referencia).

Por lo tanto, al final tanto la variable `textoOrdenado` como `arrayTexto` apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria y lo que alteres en una se altera en la otra (realmente se altera siempre la misma, sólo que ambas variables apuntan allí).

Una analogía es que tienes un vaso lleno de agua y dos o mas personas que lo sostienen, cada persona puede decir que sostiene un vaso lleno (por lo tanto puedes creer que hay varios vasos, pero en realidad es el mismo). Si una de las persona consume la mitad del agua, todas las demás verán que su vaso ahora tiene la mitad de agua, aunque ellas no la hayan consumido.

En el caso de los Objetos, clonarlos (hacer una copia) puede ser una tarea nada trivial, y existen al menos dos tipos de copia: [`shallow copy` y `deep copy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying), pero eso es otro asunto.

Answer (score 2):

Se debe a que `sort()` no crea un nuevo arreglo como lo hacen otras funciones como `filter` o `map`.

`sort` ordena el arreglo y devuelve una referencia al mismo arreglo.

```
let arrayTexto=Array.from(texto); 
let textoOrdenado=arrayTexto;
textoOrdenado.sort();
```

De esa forma `arrayTexto` tiene el arreglo original y esa referencia se asigna a `textoOrdenado`. Ambas variables apuntan al mismo arreglo. Cuando se ejecuta `textoOrdenado.sort()`, se está modificando el único arreglo que existe y por eso  parece que ambas variables se afectan pero no es así, son dos variables que apuntan a un mismo arreglo.

Comment: Vale, esto lo veo mas claro, y todo esto quien te lo explica para que uno no acabe loco??..jeje Muchas gracias ¡¡¡¡

Comment: Eso puede encontrarse en la documentación de cada método https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort En la descripción del método dice si retorna un nuevo arreglo o si solo modifica el arreglo original.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos cuestiones, cuando hacemos una asignación en JavaScript (`=`) **no** estamos haciendo una copia, estamos añadiendo una referencia mas a un lugar de la memoria, exepto si se trata de datos de tipo primitivo (string, number, bigint, boolean, undefined, symbol, y null), que al ser inmutables, **si** crean una copia en una asignación. Es por ello que:

```js
let variable = "un_string"; // <-- Siendo la variabe un primitivo

let otra_variable = variable; // <-- se copia

console.log(variable);     

variable.toUpperCase(); // <-- No se altera "variable"

console.log(variable);

variable = variable.toUpperCase(); // <-- Tampoco se altera, se reasigna "variable"

console.log(variable);

console.log(otra_variable); // <--  Tampoco se altera
```

Los datos **que no son de tipo primitivo** son mutables, es por ello que `.push()` o `.sort()` pueden alterar el objeto original, y por consiguiente todas las referencias que este tenga, van a reflejar la misma mutación.

Lo que es confuso, es que existen muchos métodos que retornan una copia de un tipo **no** primitivo, `.map()` o `.reduce()` no alteran el objeto original, sino que retornan una copia "alterada" o mutada, dejando la original intacta.

Es por ello que si queremos hacer un `.sort()` sin alterar el array original, tenemos que copiar el array usando algún método que retorne **otro** array, una forma corta es usando la desestructuración `[...array]` pero podría ser cualquier forma que retorne otro array.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que en realidad quieres hacer tu es lo siguiente:

```
let texto = "hola"; //Texto
let arrayTexto = Array.from(texto); //array1
let textoOrdenado = Array.from(texto); //array2
textoOrdenado.sort(); //Ordenamos array2
console.log(arrayTexto) //Mostramos array1
console.log(textoOrdenado) //Mostramos array2
```

Salidas:

```
arrayTexto - ["h", "o", "l", "a"]
textoOrdenado - ["a", "h", "l", "o"]
```

Comment: Así es, eso es lo que quiero hacer, aún así ,le estoy diciendo que textoOrdenado sea igual a arrayTexto , no al contrario, en ningún momento le he dicho a la variable arrayTexto que tome el valor de textoOrdenado...esque se conmutan o algo??

Comment: No recuerdo exactamente como era la explicación, pero javascript carga aun cuando las cosas ya se han mostrado. Por ejemplo, tengo un a = [4], a este lo imprimo, y luego le hago un push del numero 2, ese 2 ya aparecerá dentro del array sin tener que mostrarlo de nuevo.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/3f8b36b515c797deedec72db095d012e.gif

Comment: okis, me estaba volviendo loco, muchas gracias ¡¡¡